# WordPress ignoring php.ini upload max file size

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a WordPress site (not MU), I have set upload_max_filesize = 50M, post_max_size=50M in php.ini. The results of phpinfo() function show the value to be 50M but in WordPress Media uploader Max upload file size is still 32M.

I have also tried to write this code in the theme's functions.php:

> @ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '50M' );
>   @ini_set( 'post_max_size', '50M');

Also tried deactivating all plugins, changed theme but no resort, WordPress still says 32 Mb.

Can anyone guide me what can be wrong here?

Comment: did you had any luck with this?

Comment: Yes! Turns out the web host had applied a hard limit on these parameters. No matter what I'd do it won't go beyond 32M. I moved away from GoDaddy.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, and the other answers didn't completely work for me, and I'm apparently not alone, so here's what I did to make it work.

1. Locate your php.ini files: sudo find / -name "php*.ini" -print. This will give you an idea of where any configuration files might be hiding.
2. Open them one at a time (you may need sudo).
3. Check to see if they have a line "upload_max_filesize=##" where ## is some value (i.e. 250M). You shouldn't have to add any of the lines. This should already be in the file.
4. You will need to change the line "post_max_size=##" to be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize.

Notes:

Supposedly, you can do "php -i | grep php.ini" to see which configuration file is being used, but changing the indicated file did not work for me. I changed one that lived at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini to make it work. Some trial and error will be needed, but give this a shot.

Comment: definitely the post_max_size which also need, for example when uploading themes, media   etc..

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to achieve what you need , here are three ways you can use any one of these

1) Using functions file: Copy and paste the code below to functions.php file

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize' , '50M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '50M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

2) Try using htaccess method by adding the code below:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

3) Last method, php.ini file that you are already trying

```
upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had already tried two ways out of these 3, I tried htaccess one too but after adding that code to htaccess file the server starts throwing 500 internal server error.

I believe the problem is something else, because when I rand phpinfo() function it shows the 'upload_max_filesize' value as 50.

Comment: Try adding a php.ini inside wordpress wp-admin folder. It will work.

Comment: For folks with multisite enabled, in the admin area go to My Sites -> Network Admin -> Settings and scroll down to "Max upload file size". The default for multisite caps this to 1,500KB. I changed these PHP settings in a million places before discovering THIS was what was limiting me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of people having this problem the best way to fix it is by creating a new php.ini inside your wp-admin folder.

1.Connect to your site via FTP or File Manager 2.Navigate to wp-admin folder 3.Create a file inside the wp-admin folder called php.ini 4.Add in this line: max_input_vars = 5000 5.Save

I wrote a quick blog article on it here too: [Increasing Your Max_input_vars Value](https://jonnyjordan.com/blog/how-to-increase-the-menu-items-limit-in-wordpress/)

Comment: You are correct .
Adding a php.ini inside wordpress wp-admin folder worked for me.

Comment: Very interesting.  Adding the file to the root did nothing.  Adding it to /wp-admin/ made it work.

Answer (score 2):

This was absolute insanity. I almost went crazy looking for a solution.

My `wp-admin/php.ini` was getting completely ignored.
I changed `/etc/apache2/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`, still nothing, it was getting ignored.
Turns out it was getting settings from `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using multisite keep in mind that there is a max_upload_filesize setting for the network.

[image: WordPress multisite settings]